# Modifying Drupal 8 administration theme

Tags: themes, drupal-8

I've recently added the faqfield module - but when reviewing this in the content editor the fields are spewing over the container.

I fixed the issue by adjusting the textarea.form-textarea css to min-width:100% in chrome console -- but I am not sure how to apply this fix to the site itself. Is there a way of adding into the db level an override css for the admin theme? Or do I create an overriding change in the theme folder - and if so how?

before quick fix
[image]

after quick fix
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new custom admin theme and have it use the contributed admin theme you're using as a base.

You can then just override stuff as needed:

In your my_theme.info.yml in the top section add:

```
base theme: contrib_admin_theme_name
```

You then use your own custom theme as the admin theme, but it well use everything from the contributed admin theme, except for the stuff you overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to go to Drupal.org and submit it as a patch (you'd be doing it in the Drupal core issue queue since Seven is a core theme). If you don't want to do that then you'd create a [subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme) based on the Seven theme, and add your CSS in there. You don't wan to update the theme directly as anytime you update the Drupal core it'll overwrite your changes.

Comment: Where do you submit the patch to drupal org -- I wasn't sure if it would be something that should come from the module itself

Comment: Since it's a core theme it would be via the core issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal

And here is info on contributing a patch: https://www.drupal.org/patch/submit